# Проблема с питоном в ububtu

Tags: python, ubuntu

При установке программы выскакивает ошибка

```
Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/NoSQLMap-0.7-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for NoSQLMap==0.7
Searching for requests==2.5.0
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/
Couldn't find index page for 'requests' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for requests==2.5.0
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('requests==2.5.0')
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Какая версия pip? Пробовали обновить?

Answer (score 1):

Узнать версию pip можно так `pip --version`. Если ниже 10.0.1, то обновляете `pip install --upgrade pip`.

Если работается с Python 3, то `pip3 --version` и `pip3 install --upgrade pip`

UPD

Обновите индекс пакетов и сами пакеты

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Проверьте версию pip, если она не изменилась, то она установлена не через менеджер пакетов. С помощью команды `whereis pip` узнайте местоположение и удалите pip. Затем установите актуальную версию менеджера пакетов (Для python2 и python3).

```
apt-get install python-pip 
apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: Версия 1.0 При обновлении выдает ошибку   Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/

Comment: @Komarov111 тогда соберите из исходников, или установите через apt.